# "No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Reddit/d8326aa.jpg" thrown for no reason

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view/ library to load one image of mine by just passing the correct (existing) path
like:

```
setImage(path)
```

and the "No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Reddit/d8326aa.jpg" is a message from exception. However if loading the image like:

```
setImage(Uri.fromFile(File(path)).toString())
```

that works but the image is blurry for some reason. Other apps that use this library and load the same image are not blurry and all functionality works.

Comment: The documentation shows `setImage(ImageSource.uri(path))` as the syntax to use. Beyond that, consider editing your question and providing the complete stack trace.

Comment: I am using this one sorry https://github.com/tibbi/subsampling-scale-image-view, it's the kotlin version. It's pretty much the same, just the ImageSource is deleted and it's handled in the setImage() method

Comment: Perhaps use the original library rather than this version.

Comment: The original version doesn't have rotation handling.

Comment: "blurry" implies scaling is going on.  Change the imageview's scaling type.  Note that you don't know HOW other apps are using this library.  They may be pre-processing the image after loading it somehow.